# Adding an Looped number to each class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, variables, for-loop

Im trying to add a number to the classes `hand`. Each one of them are suppose to have a number that will increase by one the further you go down the page. I thought I could do this with the `FOR` loop but I don't know how!

This is the code I have so far but I dont know what to put between the `FOR` loop:

```
$(".hand").each(function(){
         var i = 0;
         for (i=0;i<=20;i++){

         }
});
```

Any Ideas?

**Edit:**

HTML Exampe:

```
<div class="hand effect"><br>
   <div class="outer">
   <a href="" class="title">Text</a>
   <span class="inner">
   Text More Text.
  </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want the end result to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) provides the index for you.

```
$(".hand").each(function(index,element){
    $(this).append('<span class="index">' + (++index) + '</span>');   // example of appending a span tag to them
});
```

Then you can style each of the span tags using the class `index`

Comment: May i ask why you're taking this approach in the first place ? There's probably a better way to do what you want to do

Comment: No, I have like 26 elements with a class called: Hand. And in the top right corner I want to have each of the elements numbered. Like:

First box on page - has number 0, 
second box on page - has number 1....and so on....

Comment: What kind of elements are these ? Can you post some sample HTML ?

Comment: Look at my edit, i have added some sample code that appends a span tag into the element which contains the index.

Comment: This works but I actually don't want a 0. SO thats why I want to use loop.

Comment: @Shawn31313  If you don't want zero add 1 to the index. `$(this).append('<span class="index">' + (index + 1) + '</span>'`

Comment: Great, on more question. Is there a way to not count the index of an hidden .hand?

Comment: See my edit, that should be what you want. Well this is a loop, and in your loop you start off at 0, hence i assumed that's what you wanted.

Comment: Sure change your selector $(".hand:visible")

Comment: By not count, do you mean skip that element and not display the number, as well as preserving the current index ?